# How can i build project in visual studio 2012 on both way(dll and lib) together

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll, static-libraries

I managed to set up build project in dll mode and in library mode but not together:

for build in dll:

- project->properties->Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)
- project->properties->Target Extension: .dll

for build in library:

- project->properties->Configuration Type: Static library (.lib)
- project->properties->Target Extension:  .lib

it is possible to build both of them together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have single project that can be used for .dll and .lib.

Steps to be followed:

1. Visual Studio will provide you Debug and Release solution
   configurations. Create custom configurations for lib and dll (i.e.
   lib-release, dll-release).
2. For each configuration set different project type and set export
   symbols. i.e. for lib-release define LIB_CONFIG and don't set it for
   dll-release.
3. In code file use LIB_CONFIG with #IFDEF to include/exclude project
   type specific code. IF some part of code is lib specific the add it
   in #ifdef LIB_CONFIG...#endif, and if it is dll specific add it in
   #ifndef LIB_CONFIG...#endif.
4. Compile project after changing Active solution configuration. i.e.
   change to lib-release, if you want to have .lib file.

I hope this will help you. Please let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

During creation of new project in Visual Studio, make sure you check on "Export Symbols"

Comment: I don't think that's an answer. A .lib file is either an import library or a static library.

Comment: Really? So your build produces two lib files? How do you do that?

Comment: It created name.lib and name.dll. Not two libs.. and I think that's what OPs question was. How to create dll and lib at once. :)

Answer (score 1):

No. You must have two projects in your solution (using the same source files). Don't forget to have different names for your 2 .lib files.

EDIT: use some trick to not include a DllMain function in your static lib (either some #ifdef, or a separate file not added to the static project)

Comment: I am not getting different names to lib concept?

Comment: @Digital_Reality One import lib, one static lib. If they are both built in a solution directory, it's better if they have two different names (and kind of obligatory if you want to know which one to use...)