# Compile as static and dynamic library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, compilation, static-libraries

Is it possible to create two configurations for a Visual Studio Project where one configuration compiles the code into a static, the other one into a dynamic library?

If yes, how is it done?

Comment: How about creating two projects, one for the static and one for the shared library. Then use the same code for both projects (i.e. you use the same directory to store the source for both projects).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sounds alright, but I'm pretty sure there has to be an easier way of achieving this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i build project in visual studio 2012 on both way(dll and lib) together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853577/how-can-i-build-project-in-visual-studio-2012-on-both-waydll-and-lib-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just create a new configuration in the Configuration Editor for all platforms, and name it accordingly. Then set that configuration up to build a static library manually.